# How to run a shell script once a day?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run this particular shell script only one time, daily. Here's my code for `runLucene.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from extras.download_datos_desambiguar import news_Lucene

x=datetime.today()
y=x.replace(day=x.day, hour=09, minute=00, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t=y-x

secs=delta_t.seconds+1

def fourdlife():
    print "checking function"
    os.system("~/code/4dlife_repo/4dbatch/src/engines/extras/download_datos_desambiguar/news_Lucene.py")



t = Timer(secs, fourdlife)
t.start()
print "timer started"
```

I am running this code in my `ProcesosContinuous.py` file like this:

```
while True:
            os.system("./runl.sh")
            #some other processes
```

where `runl.sh` is

```
python ~/code/4dlife_repo/4dbatch/src/engines/extras/download_datos_desambiguar/news_Lucene.py
```

This python code is always running on my `apache2` server.

However, this is working at any given hour and not just the specified hour. What am I doing wrong?
Also, I feel there is a much better way to do this. I looked at the `cron` task but that's not what I am looking for. I don't want my program to go to `sleep()` because I need the other processes to run after the `runl.sh` process. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain why `cron` is not good for you? It is exactly it's purpose.

Comment: because I read somewhere, it is the same as putting the code to `sleep()` till the next time it is supposed to run.

Comment: @eugene, I am calling the shell script from my python code. please read the question carefully before commenting.

Comment: Reading carefully: " Here's my code for runl.sh:" and here comes python code. So?

Comment: "I am running this code in my `ProcesosContinuous.py`. Does that mean anything?

Comment: "Somewhere" is not a good technical source. `cron` has a daemon, that is running in background and doing scheduled jobs.  The job will go to sleep only if designed in this way. As for your other remark, the sentence is related to the second snippet. This is how the question is written. If you mean anything else - you are welcome to edit it.

Comment: @kaushaya, cron doesn't even call `sleep()` inside *your* code -- the cron daemon is a separate process; it **can't** call functions inside your code; it only puts **the cron daemon itself** to sleep. And whether it calls `sleep()` or uses a `select()` call with a timeout or uses some other mechanism to wait inside its own code is pure implementation detail, and has no effect whatsoever on how your code runs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set up cron task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057629/how-do-you-set-up-cron-task)

Comment: @kenorb , I already tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: @eugene, what you are trying to say makes no sense. I have a shelll script. I am calling it from an external python script. It's that simple. Unless you have any useful solution, please refrain from this pointless banter.

Comment: @kaushaya Maybe it doesn't work, because you're using relative paths (`~/`) in your script, change them to absolute, otherwise it won't work. The same in cron, you've to specify absolute path to your script.

Comment: "BTW, sh extensions are typical for shell scripts, but you are using python, so she extension should be py". This is what you told me in the beginning which has got nothing to do with any kind of help. I respect people trying to help, but when there comes a comment which has got nothing to do with my code and is so incorrect that I don't know how to respond to it. No harm intended, don't worry.

Answer (score 5):

The command `crontab -e` will open up an interactive editor within which you can define a cron job.

Within that editor's buffer, you can then enter a line such as the following (and then save it):

```
00 00 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

This command will run `script.sh` every midnight.

Comment: It says .sh:1 :17 : not found.

Comment: `p=subprocess.call("00 00 * * * lrunl.sh",shell=True)`

Comment: `/bin/sh : 1: 00` not found.

Comment: @kaushaya, the string starting with `00` is content that's supposed to be put inside the crontab file, not a command to run itself. (Also, as a general rule, don't use `shell=True` without a good reason; it opens you up to whole classes of bugs [shell injection, shellshock, etc] that would be otherwise avoided).

Comment: @kaushaya, I assume you're trying to write Python code that configures the crontab; is this correct? The answer here is written assuming a manual process. Is there a reason you want it to be Python? Would a shell script be acceptable?

Comment: Open terminal, type crontab -e. It will open cronjobs configuration window. At this window paste the command that i gave you and change the path to asbolute script path, save and exit.

Comment: Do you understand this solution? This is the correct way to schualed programs / scripts

Comment: Yes I do, thank you. But I typed exactly what you told me, still not working. Check my comment on the answer below.

Comment: Is there any way I can view the output?

Answer (score 0):

cron is always doing its thing, I think it's quite a bit better to use that rather than having a python script dedicated to constantly checking if it's time to run the shell script.

With that said, when you create the crontab, it'll go under the users crontab, so just watch the user and/or -u it.

Comment: Can you please assist with some code? I find cron rather challenging for some reason.

Comment: I'm adding this `59 15 * * * /bin/sh /code/4dlife_repo/4dbatch/src/engines/runl.sh` but still it isn't working. I tried viewing the output via `59 15 * * * /bin/sh /code/4dlife_repo/4dbatch/src/engines/runl.sh > printoutput.txt" and still nothing.

Comment: chmod +x /code/blah/blah/blah/run1.sh and get rid of /bin/sh

Comment: Did so, still no luck.

Comment: @kaushaya can you run it from the shell? what does crontab -l say? what does a head -n 10 run1.sh say?

Comment: head -n 10 run1.sh displays the content of my shell script and yes when I manually run the shell, it works.

Comment: I'm not supposed to debug your code in this forum, but obviously when I asked what head said, and crontab -l said, I wanted the actual output. My final answer is make sure that the shell's match up. If you're trying to run a bash script on cron, tell it to run the script with bash. If it's sh, and it's still not working, and you still don't see it in crontab -l, there's probably a syntax error somewhere. All those individual problems are easily searchable here.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh
python ~/code/4dlife_repo/4dbatch/src/engines/extras/download_datos_desambiguar/news_Lucene.py
` is the output for runl.sh

Comment: crontab -l says invalid format. :/ I'm really a nood to Cron and it is already irritating!

Comment: Your'e adding extra steps. Your question, is answered with pre-requisites, right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486472/running-a-python-script-using-cron

Answer (score 0):

While 4Each's answer works on a computer that's running at the time provided in the crontab file, there is a better solution for executing daily | weekly | monthly tasks provided by [jeff](https://serverfault.com/questions/52335/job-scheduling-using-crontab-what-will-happen-when-computer-is-shutdown-during?newreg=5dfb9615cb534da4aa0a1f17321c9d57).

I will recap the most important information.

**When your computer is shut down (or the cron daemon is otherwise not running), cron jobs will not be started.**

If you have jobs that you would like to run after the fact during those times when the computer is shut down use the following directories:

```
/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.weekly
/etc/cron.monthly
```

This relies on system startup scripts and cron itself to run.

**For simple "daily", "weekly", "monthly" jobs, put a copy of or a symlink to the script in one of the /etc/cron.{daily|weekly|monthly} directories above.** This will take care of running it daily/weekly/monthly, and if your computer is off on the day the "weekly" scripts would normally run, it'll run them the next time the computer is on.