# Automate Submitting POST requests

Tags: post

I would like to automatically submit a form that I get sent everyday (POST, type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Its a simple form with an  option 1 and option 2 button then a submit. I was hoping to automate this sending so that the form is submitted on a regular basis. Thanks for any help and sorry for my terrible understanding :p

Comment: you should probably look at writing. a script with curl https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html but in case there is something that prevents it being automated in this manner I think you should provide an example of the html you are sent, and how you are receiving it - for example in outlook, you get an sms that links to page, you get it in gmail. etc.

Comment: @user254694 Thanks for the reply - Yes so its a link emailed via outlook however I've noticed its the same URL except every day the value at the end of the URL increases by one. (e.g www.example.com/1234 then the next day it will be www.example.com/1235)

Comment: so look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214926/how-to-run-a-shell-script-once-a-day for how to run a script once per day, and then look at curl to construct some script that posts the values you want to a number incremented once per day. One you have an example of some code that you think should do what you want but doesn't make a new question with that code and probably somebody will help you get it all the way done.